# Ruby: How is self assigned when calling parent's class method

Tags: ruby

```
class Foo
  def self.try_one
    puts self
  end
end


class Bar < Foo
  def self.try_two
    try_one
  end
end

class Car < Foo
  def self.try_three
    Foo.try_one
  end
end
```

Foo.try_one => Foo

Bar.try_two => Bar

Car.try_one => Foo

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

I don't really understand why Bar.try_two results in Bar when Car.try_three results in Foo.

Does try_one and Foo.try_one (which I thought were the same thing since they're both inherited) change the context of self? Couldn't really find any resources on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `try_one` is defined on the "class object" of Foo, its `self` will always resolve into Foo.

Comment: @ibug yeah, that's what I thought too but calling `try_two` which calls `try_one` instead of `Foo.try_one` returns `Bar` as `self` which is really confusing me.

Comment: You're explicitly calling `Foo.try_one`, so why'd you expect `self` to resolve to the caller? Foo is not Car after all.

Comment: ‍♀️ I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: This is all a bit of a weird example, because you're defining/calling methods on the class object, instead of instances.

Comment: if you do `class Foo; def try_one; puts self; end; end` and `Car.new.try_one`, you'll see a less confusing example where `self` is still an instance of `Car`!

Comment: By making `Bar` a subclass of `Foo`, it inherits all of its parent’s methods – `Bar` can access `try_one` as if it were its very own method, including `self` which refers to `Bar`. But if you send `try_one` directly to `Foo`, you bypass that inheritance and the method gets evaluated in the scope of the parent.

Comment: @stefan Yes exactly why I got confused (which was a very stupid mistake after hearing the explanations though). Thanks everyone for replying!